# Array doesn't print content

Tags: java, arrays, string, int, tostring

I am trying to print array's content with

```
toString()
```

and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

The output should be 5 random numbers from 0 to 100 which I will store in array after all I have to print them all.

Here is my code:

```
public class Ary {

private int[] anArray;
private int arraySize;
private String numberAsString;
Random r = new Random();

public Ary(int arraySize) {
    this.anArray = printArray();
}

public Ary() {
    arraySize = 2;
    printArray();
}

public int getArraySize() {
    return arraySize;
}

public void setArraySize(int arraySize) {
    this.arraySize = arraySize;
}

public int[] printArray() {
    // Assign anArray with a custom number
    anArray = new int[arraySize];

    for(int numbers : anArray) {
        anArray[numbers] = r.nextInt(100);
        System.out.println(anArray[numbers] + " ");
    }
    return anArray;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Array = " + Arrays.toString(anArray);
}
}
```

Output:

```
Music.app.Ary@5e2de80c
```

Here is my code with Arrays.toString():

```
public int[] printArray() {
    // Assign anArray with a custom number
    anArray = new int[arraySize];

    for(int numbers : anArray) {
        anArray[numbers] = r.nextInt(100);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(anArray));
    }
    return anArray;
}
```

I've already tried tons of methods but still haven't figure it out.. Can you please explain what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Java arrays don't override `Object.toString()`. You can use `Arrays.toString()`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've already tried it, still gave me the same output

Comment: @S.Anthony Are you sure? `Arrays.toString(anArray);` should work just fine.

Comment: @AndrewL. One second, I will add this code too

Comment: Please don't edit you question to add things like "(solved)" in the title, and invalidate answers by correcting your code. If you managed to solve your own problem, post an answer with your solution (or accept the answer that helped you solved the problem). I have reverted your last edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've changed the signature of `toString()` (so you aren't calling the method you have defined). Instead, you need something like<sup>**1**</sup>,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Array = " + Arrays.toString(anArray);
}
```

And you should probably initialize `anArray` in your constructor(s)<sup>**2**</sup> and remove "`printArray`"

```
public Ary(int arraySize) {
    this.arraySize = arraySize;
    this.anArray = new int[arraySize];
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        this.anArray[i] = r.nextInt(101); // <-- [0, 100], or [0, 101)
    }
}

public Ary() {
    this(5); // <-- use the other constructor.
}
```

<sup>**1**<sub>And the override annotation will alert you to this mistake.</sub></sup>
<sup>**2**<sub>And you shouldn't print the array until you finish initializing it.</sub></sup>

Comment: Hm...interesting. Now I am getting this: `Array = [ ]`

Comment: @S.Anthony And where / how are you initializing the array now?

Comment: I updated my code

Comment: Found my mistake, works well. Thank you very much Elliott

Answer (score 1):

This is a custom method  `System.out.print(array.toString());`
so you overloaded the **toString()** BUT for printing out the object in the console is the toString() method (no params) what is getting invoked...

remove the int[] parameter and it will called normally, you need for sure modify the body of the method too

```
public String toString() {
    return "Array = " + Arrays.toString(a);
}
```

ussing teh override annotation will be recommended always, it will prevent that errors while writing the code....

Comment: You might want the `@Override` annotation there to override Object's method

Comment: Also, it isn't clear where `a` came from here.